# Restart File writing after certain number of lines

Tags: java, android, file, io, outputstream

I'm working in Android trying to write some lines into a file. After a certain amount of lines, say 100, I want the file to delete the first line, and then append a line to the end. So basically, I want to keep writing to the file but keep the limit at 100 lines. I have been reading and found the files in java aren't to friendly with what I'm trying to do. I haven't found anything here either http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

Is there a better way of keeping a file to the limit of 100 lines, and deleting the oldest lines when adding the new lines after that?

More specifically, I want a textView to display the 100 most recent events that a service has sent.

As of now, I have this method to display my STORETEXT file,

```
public void readFileInEditor() {
    try {
        InputStream in = openFileInput(STORETEXT);
        if (in != null) {
            InputStreamReader tmp = new InputStreamReader(in);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(tmp);
            String str;
            StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
            while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buf.append(str + "\n");
            }
            in.close();
            writelog.setText(buf.toString());
        }
    } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
        // that's OK, we probably haven't created it yet
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Exception: " + t.toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

and I write to the file like this...

```
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(
                STORETEXT, MODE_APPEND));
        out.write("Some User Activity");
        out.write("\n");
        out.close();
```

I want to modify my code to only write the 100 most recent activities, and then set that to my textView. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the reason that you want to save 100 strings to file? To reuse them at restart of your app?

Comment: Hello @greenapps , thank you for the response. I have a log activity, where users can see when they have logged on and off as well as when notifications have been triggered or dismissed from a service. I am saving these events by writing them to a text file, and then displaying the text file when the user opens up the activity that shows their recent events.

Comment: As removing a first line from a file implies rewriting the whole file you could do it a bit different. Use an ArrayList<String> where you add your strings. Before adding a string check if max 100 is reached. If so remove the first entry (this is very easy) and then add the string. Then save the whole array list to file.  At startup just read the file in the array list.

Comment: Okay, so instead of trying to manipulate the text file directly, I'll use  an ArrayList to just overwrite and write to the file? I'm currently working on a method that counts the line numbers using a BufferedReader and then using that to check if the file is over 100 lines. And if it is, I just readline() and continue and save the rest of the lines to a buffer and then overwrite my old file, how does that sound for a solution as well? Should i give up on that? @greenapps

Comment: No that does not sound good. Using anarray list is much easier. But... it's up to you...

Comment: Okay, I'll try your approach and post up a solution if I make any progress. Thanks for your help.

Comment: As far as i understand now you only have to save the array list to file at program exit. And use onSaveInstanceState at orientation change.